# Union query fails since some of the servers are down / offline at the time of query run

Tags: sql, union

I have a UNION query like below and running this from server which is having the other 40 servers are Linked servers.

```
Select * from server 1 UNION ALL

select * from server 2 UNION ALL

select * from server 3 ......... and so on
```

When any one of the server from the above query is offline (example: Server 2 is offline / down) the entire reports / query is failing.

Please suggest a solution

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You don't select from a server, you select from a **table**. Your "sample" queries - or at least the names used make no sense to me.

Comment: Cache the results on your local server.  You can even have an agent job (or a job per table, to have the updates done in parallel) constantly checking for and bringing in any changes that have occurred.  You can then query your local tables instead, while also having a readiness status showing how up to date the various cached results are.

Answer (score 3):

A single query either succeeds or fails -- and queries require that the tables they access be available.

The most sensible solution is to run each query separately, catching any errors if they occur. You can *insert* the results -- one by one -- into a result table. However, you will need to catch the errors.

You haven't specified the database you are using. Most have scripting languages that provide functionality to help with this. I will caution that handling server errors adds considerable complexity, as compared to a single query.